# The slotted plane for countable lines through $z$ removed.

Tags: general-topology

At each point $z$ in the plane, the basic neighborhoods at $z$ are to be the sets {$z$} $\cup A$, where $A$ is a disk about $z$ with a finite number of straight lines through $z$ removed.
That this gives a topology on the plane. But, what happen if we re-replace "finite" in the definition of this space with "countable"?

Could you help to answer that quiestion?

Comment: One answer to "what happens" is "that makes some other topology", just like any choice of basic neighborhoods would make. What do you want to know more specifically?

Comment: Is still a topology with countable lines through z removed?

Answer (score 2):

The family $\mathcal S$ with a countable number of straight lines through $z$ removed, which you described is not a base of a topology. Indeed, let $z=0$ and $A$ be a unit open disc centered at $0$ with countably many  radii removed, such that the endpoints of the removed radii is a dense set (in the usual topology) on the circle which bound the disk. Then any point $t$ of $A$ does not have a “neighborhood” of the form $\{t\}\cup B\subset A$, where $B$ is a disc (with a non-zero radius) centered at $t$ with countably many  radii removed.

Thus if we want to define a topology $\tau$ on the plane in  which all elements of $\mathcal S$ are open, we should to consider the family $\mathcal S$ not as a base of $\tau$, but, for instance, as its subbase.

Comment: $B$ is a disc centered at $z$, is it not at $t$?

Comment: @lepstein Yes, thanks. Corrected.